# Drupal 7 MySQL master/slave replication not working

Tags: mysql, drupal, database-replication

I am having trouble getting Drupal 7.7 to use a MySQL slave database.

My settings.php is as follows:

```
$databases['default']['default'] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'my_db',
  'username' => 'dbuser',
  'password' => 'dbpw',
  'host' => 'db-ip-address'
);
$databases['default']['slave'][] = array(
  'driver' => 'mysql',
  'database' => 'my_db',
  'username' => 'dbuser',
  'password' => 'dbpw',
  'host' => '127.0.0.1'
);
```

Replication itself is working great. When I add new content to the site it quickly is replicated on the slave.

Looking at tcpdump though, I never see a call to the local database.

Is there anything I'm missing to enable Drupal to use the slave?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using slave databases is barely implemented in Drupal core. If you are developing your own modules then calls to [db_query](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/db_query/7) need to specify that they want to use the slave database using the $options array. See [DatabaseConnection::defaultOptions](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--database--database.inc/function/DatabaseConnection%3A%3AdefaultOptions/7) for how to set this array.

Comment: Thanks James, This was also answered for me on drupal.org. http://drupal.org/node/1253352 Looks like only 'Search' and 'Aggregator' can make use of a slave.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has a really good answer to this same question:
https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/10806/how-to-get-core-to-leverage-a-mysql-master-slave-configuration

It is indeed possible to rather easily make most of core and contrib use slave server for selects, without patching core :)

Answer (score 0):

The [AutoSlave](https://drupal.org/project/autoslave) module redirects `SELECT` queries to read-only replicant databases, ***and*** it takes into account replication lag.

According to the module docs, it only uses the read-only replicant when all of the following conditions are true:

> 1. The query is a select query
> 2. The tables in the select query have not been written to during the request and within the assumed replication lag
> 3. A transaction has not been started
> 4. The tables in the select query are not specified in the 'tables' option in the driver settings
> 5. A lock has not been started (core db-lock and memcache-lock supported)